# Problem with recursive implementation of Subspace Iteration method in Numpy

Tags: numerics, iterative-method, numpy

I am having trouble with implementing the method of subspace iteration to find the eigenvalues and vectors of a random, symmetric matrix, `A` that is mxm with m = 10. The function that I have written to perform this task is

```
def subspaceiterate(A,V,v,j):
    if j == 0:
        return v
    else:
        v_jm1 = V[:,j-1]
        v_jm1 = np.reshape(v_jm1,(np.size(V,axis=0),1))
        v = v - np.matmul(v_jm1.T,np.matmul(A,v_jm1))
        j = j - 1
        return subspaceiterate(A,V,v,j)
```

where `A` is my symmetric data matrix, `V` is an mxm matrix whose columns represent the current, calculated state of the eigenvectors, `v` is a particular mx1 column of`V` that represents a particular eigenvector and `j` is the position of `v`in `V`.

As I understand it, the basic idea of Subspace Iteration is to simultaneously perform a Power Iteration on the different `v`'s while subtracting away the components of `v` that are in the direction of the eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues larger than the one associated with the particular `v` in question. I have tried to design this function to operate in such a capacity but the results I get do not support the aforementioned idea. All the eigenvalues converge quickly (as they should), but do so to a value very close to the largest one instead of to the different, distinct eigenvalues (whose values I know because I have calculated them beforehand with `np.linalg.eigs()`).

The `v`'s are normalized in the program before and after the function is called and the eigenvalues calculated with the Rayleigh-Taylor quotient `v_j.T*A*v_j` (implemented with `np.matmul()`). At this point I am lost and hoping someone brilliant can shine some light and help me out.  `